# Java: Convert String "\uFFFF" into char

Tags: java, unicode

Is there a standard method to convert a string like "\uFFFF" into character meaning that the string of six character contains a presentation of one unicode character?

Comment: do you mean like::
System.out.println("Enter a Character:");
    String s = read.readLine();
    char c = s.charAt(0);

Comment: Actually the edit by jleedev is wrong: Dima said his string had 6 characters, not seven.  Internally, even in Java, a "string" doesn't contain two backslashes.  I read the original version as "\uFFFF", a "generic" string, without escaping, because the poster used the lowercase "string" word and not "String" and because he precisely stated that the string was made of 6 characters.
  So technically, I'm pretty sure the string he wants to convert is "\uFFFF", and *not* "\\uFFFF".

The fact that in a Java source code you have to enter "\uFFFF" as "\\uFFFF" is, to me, unrelated to the question.

Comment: rolled it back. let the author define the context of the question better.

Comment: Fair enough, but the fact that the backslash wasn't escaped seemed to be confusing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
char c = "\uFFFF".toCharArray()[0];
```

The value is directly interpreted as the desired string, and the whole sequence is realized as a single character.

Another way, if you are going to hard-code the value:

```
char c = '\uFFFF';
```

Note that `\uFFFF` doesn't seem to be a proper unicode character, but try with `\u041f` for example.

[Read about unicode escapes here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html)

Comment: I think he meant for the string literal that has 6 characters, with two backslashes in the source code, like "\\uFFFF".

Comment: nothing. I don't quite graps the context behind the question actually.

Comment: @Bozho that makes two of us :)

Comment: I don't know... maybe it's just because I've run across this a few times before but it seemed obvious to me. :)  If you are reading  certain sort text, or more commonly RDF files (like n-quads) it is quite common to read literal \uFFFF and need to convert it to a real char code.

Comment: Still, some short sample code would have clarified, I suppose.

Comment: @Bozo, only that `char c = Character.valueOf('\uFFFF');` seemed overly complex to me :-)

Comment: so you did grasp the context :)

Comment: The value \uFFFF "is guaranteed not to be a 
Unicode character at all" : http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf

Answer (score 21):

The backslash is escaped here (so you see two of them but the *s* String is really only 6 characters long).  If you're *sure* that you have exactly "\u" at the beginning of your string, simply skip them and converter the hexadecimal value:

```
String s = "\\u20ac";

char c = (char) Integer.parseInt( s.substring(2), 16 );
```

After that *c* shall contain the euro symbol as expected.

Comment: This is what I do when I need this.

Comment: char c = (char) Integer.parseInt( s.substring(2), 16 ); - looks very much what I meant. \uFFFF is a format of how Unicode is presented in where I read it from (say ASCII file), not a literal. I magined that there could be a more direct method, but this one should be also fine. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 19):

If you are parsing input with Java style escaped characters you might want to have a look at [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)). It handles Unicode escapes as well as newlines, tabs etc.

```
String s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u20ac\\n"); // s contains the euro symbol followed by newline
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String charInUnicode = "\\u0041"; // ascii code 65, the letter 'A'
Integer code = Integer.parseInt(charInUnicode.substring(2), 16); // the integer 65 in base 10
char ch = Character.toChars(code)[0]; // the letter 'A'
```

Comment: Why do you use toChars() when you hard-code `[0]` anyway? Your code goes half-way to supporting high unicode codepoints but misses the other half. What's the point?

Comment: Why not jsut type-cast the integer directly to a `char`? It is already in the valid range: `char ch = (char) code;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in BlueJ --> `char c ='\uffff'; System.out.println(c);`
Hi,
I loved the way everyone understood it but after I tried it in BlueJ, it shows a blank screen...

But after you copy the only (invisible) character and paste it on the google search bar, it becomes clear that it responds well but the output screen was unable to display it...

The specific outcome was this character -->

Have a nice day experimenting!