# Java Char to its unicode hexadecimal string representation and vice-versa

Tags: java, parsing, unicode, char, hex

I need to generate the hexadecimal code of Java characters into strings, and parse those strings again later. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126378/java-convert-string-uffff-into-char) that parsing can be performed as following:

```
char c = "\u041f".toCharArray()[0];
```

I was hoping for something more elegant like [Integer.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for parsing.

How about generating the hexadecimal unicode properly?

Comment: I posted an answer but I think I may be doing it backwards from what you want. Could you clarify with an example of the output your looking for?

Comment: Say, for character ö, I would like '00F6' as listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: OK, then my answer should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some deeper reading, the javadoc says the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) methods based on `char` parameters do not support all unicode values, but those taking code points (i.e., `int`) do.

Hence, I have been performing the following test:

```
    int codePointCopyright = Integer.parseInt("00A9", 16);

    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(codePointCopyright));
    System.out.println(Character.isValidCodePoint(codePointCopyright));

    char[] toChars = Character.toChars(codePointCopyright);
    System.out.println(toChars);

    System.out.println();

    int codePointAsian = Integer.parseInt("20011", 16);

    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(codePointAsian));
    System.out.println(Character.isValidCodePoint(codePointAsian));

    char[] toCharsAsian = Character.toChars(codePointAsian);
    System.out.println(toCharsAsian);
```

and I am getting:

[image]

Therefore, I should not talk about `char` in my question, but rather about array of chars, since Unicode characters can be represented with more than one `char`. On the other side, an `int` covers it all.

Comment: Well you're right to talk about char in your question, it's Java that's broken and forces the coder to meddle with strings at encoding detail level WRT to Unicode supplementary.

Comment: @BaselShishani Java isn't "broken". Unicode had no supplementary planes when Java first came out, and a char could handle any Unicode code point. Conversions between the various encodings and Java primitives can certainly be confusing sometimes, but efficiently representing all the characters for all the world's languages (and more) is inherently complex, and Unicode is still constantly evolving. There is a point at which you can't and shouldn't mask the complexities of processing Unicode data from the user. Don't blame Java for that.

Answer (score 18):

This will generate a hex string representation of the char:

```
char ch = 'ö';
String hex = String.format("%04x", (int) ch);
```

And this will convert the hex string back into a char:

```
int hexToInt = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
char intToChar = (char)hexToInt;
```

Comment: First one gives me > Cannot cast from char[] to int

Comment: @Holmes I had no problem using openjdk 1.8.0_65 and javac 1.8.0_60. Either using the above or `char c = '\u041f';` (which is П) or `\u4e2d' (which is 中). I couldn't compile with a Mahjong tile '' (which is out of the basic multilingual plane, and thus not representable by char so it is not surprising).

Answer (score 5):

***On String level:***
The following uses not char but int, say for Chinese, but is also adequate for chars.

```
    int cp = "\u041f".codePointAt(0);
    String s = new String(Character.toChars(cp));
```

***On native2ascii level:***
If you want to convert back and forth between `\uXXXX` and Unicode character, use from **apache, commons-lang** the `StringEscapeUtils`:

```
    String t = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(s + "ö");
    System.out.println(t);
```

On the command-line native2ascii can convert back and forth files between u-escaped and say UTF-8.