# Get Unicode Character Approx Equals to show in HTML Page

Tags: java, html, unicode, jsoup

I have a java project that builds a web page and I need to show ≈99%. I have tried a couple of things, and none of them seem to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

My project takes a template HTML file, reads it in with JSOUP, then replaces some numbers in the template and then writes that to a file.

```
Charcter.toString( (char) 257)
Character.toString("\u2248".toCharArray()[0])
Jsoup.parse("\u2248").text()
"&asymp" + "99%"
"≈" + "99%"
```

This is what I get back now.

```
<h3>â‰ˆ99%</h3>
```

[Previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126378/java-convert-string-uffff-into-char)

Comment: The problem is with your page's encoding. You have to set it properly. How is the page served to the user? You have described it all the way to a file, but it needs to get to the browser. How does it get there? Or if this is the file itself, you are writing it with the wrong encoding.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm actually creating a intermediate API that serves a toString() that when written to a file will be a webpage. Maybe I missed something at the top that sets the encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the character set for the page as UTF-8 in the HTML header.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  &asymp;99%
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I stepped out, but this feels like the right answer. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: This worked perfectly. I don't even want to say how long I tried to get this right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have got the correct codes. Simply using the HTML hex code:

```
&#x2248;
```

will give you the approx. symbol.