# [Java convert unicode from cmd to char]

Tags: java, unicode

I have the following case :

java Myprog \u03b1

And I want to read alpha value(that unicode) in a char. How could I do this in Java?

Comment: Check Bozho's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2126394/1346996).

Comment: it does not work in that way..I do not know why.

Comment: It doesn't work because in the Bozho answer the string was in the form "\u03b1". THis is a string with only 1 char in unicode format. Your string instead is "\\u03b1" that is a string of 6 characters. Check my answer to know how to convert it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the string (without \u) as an integer in hexadecimal format.
And convert it to `char`.

```
public class Myprog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(args[0].substring(2), 16 ); 
        // Use char as you like
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Davide Lorenzo MARINO