# Java convert String to Unicode character. "U+1F600" = 

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, unicode-string

Please note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126378/java-convert-string-uffff-into-char) question is not a duplicate.

I have a String like this:

```
// My String
String myString = "U+1F600";
// A method to convert the String to a real character
String unicodeCharacter = convertStringToUnicode(myString);
// Then this should print: 
System.out.println(unicodeCharacter);
```

How can I convert this String to the unicode character ? I then want to show this in a `TextView`.

Comment: Do you really want to convert the strings dynamically or do you want constant strings representing these characters?

Comment: @Henry Like in the question, I want to convert the String to the correct Unicode character. For example, `String s = “U+1F600”;` should become `String s2 = "";`. Then I want to display that emoji in a TextView. Please see edit.

Comment: First you convert the unicode codepoint to UTF-16 and encode that as a Java string literal, i.e. `String myString = "\uD83D\uDE00";`. Then you print it using a font that has the emoji.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to print the unicode when you know the code but as String...
the normal way to do this is using the method

[Character.toChars(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

like:

```
System.out.print(Character.toChars(0x1f600));
```

now in you case, you have

```
String myString = "U+1F600";
```

so you can truncate the string removing the 1st 2 chars, and then parsing the rest as an integer with the method [Integer.parseInt(valAsString, radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

## Example:

```
String myString = "U+1F600";
System.out.print(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(myString.substring(2), 16)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, as mentioned in the question, it is already a String like this: `String myString = "U+1F600"`;

Comment: yes @Pshemo , the previous was assuming the unicode to be printed was an integer... OP wants a string instead... tnxs for the review and the comments..

Comment: @Pshemo I think it looks better know, if you find something that can be improved let me know.....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yourTextVIew.setText(new String(Character.toChars(0x1F60B)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, as mentioned in the question, it is already a String like this: `String myString = "U+1F600";`.

Comment: Don't just show code fragment. Provide a bit of explanation too.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Then do `String unicodeCharacter = new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(myString.substring(2), 16)))`.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.